# How do I remove the conflict warnings in code from a stash

Tags: git, github, git-stash

So I made some changes to some translation files in a directory (note that those changes aren't done manually, they are made by a command that updates the translation files based on a project's source code). I then stashed those changes and switched to another branch where I did a `git stash pop` and tried to commit those changes but got this error message:

> error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
> [I got the same output when I tried `git merge`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYFd5.png)

So I did a `git add`, which worked. I then committed and pushed the changes.

Everything is fine except some of my files now have chunks of code framed by

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
    [code]
======= 
    [code]
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

The first [code] block seems to be the state of that part of the file before the `git stash pop` and the second one, the state after the `git stash pop`.

Those lines are an issue because my files have a xml format and aren't recognised as valid by a parser with those lines in them.

I have tried `git merge` and `git pull` but both give

> Already up-to-date.

as an output. How can I get safely git rid of those lines?

Answer (score 2):

> So I did a git add, which worked. I then committed and pushed the changes.

This is where the error lies. `git stash pop` produced merge conflicts, but you resolved those by just adding the files that needed merging, along with the conflict markers in the files. Don't do that in the future - use i.e. `git mergetool` to fix conflicts.

You state in the question that the files are generated automatically by a script, so easiest way to remedy the situation is probably to just regenerate them & commit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Reverting the commit then switching to the branch before updating the translation files worked for me